# Autocomplete in SearchBox does not work even in official example

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Today I've noticed that autocomplete in SearchBox does not on my service and when I was checking official example from Google it did not work even there.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Does anyone know what's happening? >)

**UPDATE**

This bug was handled in issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74048143.
It was marked as Fixed in version 3.32 on March 2, 2018.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the previous version of the Google Maps API worked for me. I was using v=3.exp and changed it to v=3.0

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.0&key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places"></script>`

See : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Related bug in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74048143
(from xomena's comment)

Comment: Perfect! Thnx for the answer. But still interesting that the official example is broken.

Comment: It looks like SearchBox is broken in experimental version. The corresponding bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74048143

Comment: You can use more fresh version. v.3.31 worked fine for me