# Google Maps API : SearchBox doesn't work anymore?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The eventListener on the searchBox doesn't seem to work anymore.
In the following code, the callback function is never called :

```
    var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                  new google.maps.LatLng(41.982419, -5.165268),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(51.674259, 9.912761));
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('address'), {
          bounds: defaultBounds
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
      console.log('Places', searchBox.getPlaces());
    })
```

Even on the official documentation, the example doesn't work:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

It's weird because this code was OK one week ago.

Has the API changed recently ?
Anyone is facing a similar problem ?

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue. Glad I'm not alone. It seems to me that the query to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetQueryPredictions is not returning anything

Comment: Found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049750/autocomplete-in-searchbox-does-not-work-even-in-official-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one if you want the AutoComplete Search Box

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete
```