# AutoComplete Google Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

Hi I am having trouble getting the autocomplete to display like [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). My code works on submit and displays the map properly, but **does not show results of autocomplete**. I am wondering what could be the issue.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="floating-panel">

  //this is the text field that does not display the autocomplete
  <input id="address" placeholder="Enter Starting Location" type="text"/>

  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Directions">
</div>

<div id="right-panel"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address'));
```

Here is my call to autocomplete, the API is enabled, I see calls being made on the data, but no results back:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&libraries=places&callback=initMap: {type: external, attributes: {async: true}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete in SearchBox does not work even in official example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049750/autocomplete-in-searchbox-does-not-work-even-in-official-example)

Answer (score 2):

Google maps API has new security changes in its new version, use version 3.0, this works for me:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.0&key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places" async></script>
```

Comment: I am getting `Google Maps API warning: RetiredVersion https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#retired-version` I was wondering if there a more stable version? There is frozen, new release, experimental.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing with very similar code. For me that code was working for months and just today I got a report from a user that the drop down list of locations wasn't showing anymore.

```
var input = $("input[name='location']");
var formattedAddress = input.next("input[name='formattedLocation']");
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input[0]);
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
   var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
   if (places.length == 0) {
      formattedAddress.val('');
      return;
   }

   formattedAddress.val(places[0].formatted_address);
 });
```

I was thinking that maybe we went over our daily quota, but it doesn't seem so from the Google API console. I don't see any errors in the browser console. If I look in developer tools network tab I can see requests going to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetQueryPredictions, but the responses seem rather cryptic (ex:/**/*xdc*._490z0c && *xdc*._490z0c( [4] ) ) so I can't tell if good data is coming back or not.

I'm wondering if something changed recently on the Google side that I haven't heard about.

Comment: specifying the API version in the maps url fixed it for me.  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places. Thanks @Julian Sanchez

Answer (score 0):

My temp solution: I went with the experiential version, `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.32` and noticed at the bottom of my HTML there is a tag `<div class="pac-container pac-logo hdpi">`once you start typing it updates, style this and got fixed. I sent a issue request I am hoping they are going to fix this for the stable version.

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Specify that you want to use the release version rather than the experimental if you are on the standard plan.

Comment: What exactly needs to be done that the standard feature will be used instead of the experimental one?