# Google maps SearchBox suddenly stopped showing predictions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using google map SearchBox API to get the predictions. Somehow, suddenly, it stopped showing predictions. I don't know what happens exactly. Below is my code which was working previously.

```
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
     searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
  if (places.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Clear out the old markers.
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  });
  markers = [];

 // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 places.forEach(function(place) {
  var icon = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  }));

  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
  });
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
 });
}
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AutoComplete Google Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055809/autocomplete-google-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autocomplete in SearchBox does not work even in official example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049750/autocomplete-in-searchbox-does-not-work-even-in-official-example)

Comment: [Issue in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74048143). Try using the [release version of the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions), or provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to ur js...
Google has disabled predictions in searchbox and replaced it with autocomplete.

```js
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('mapsearch'));

 autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        //   infowindow.close();
        //   marker.setVisible(false);
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
            // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(1);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setVisible(true);
          markerLocation();

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
          infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
          infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
```