# Google Places autocomplete and search not working

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Google places autocomplete dropdown is not populating any places and when I click on search i am getting this below error.

But if I do keyboard ENTER - i see the results on the map.

Everything was working fine till yesterday and nothing changed in regards to code.

```
(index):9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'handled' of undefined
    at _.Ec (js?key=AIzaSyDiIbcf012mobkCgUHnNjqRYzNCmTDeR1g&libraries=places:48)
    at HTMLInputElement. (js?key=AIzaSyDiIbcf012mobkCgUHnNjqRYzNCmTDeR1g&libraries=places:49)
    at Object.trigger (js?key=AIzaSyDiIbcf012mobkCgUHnNjqRYzNCmTDeR1g&libraries=places:119)
    at HTMLButtonElement. ((index):2699)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:338)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.min.js:311)
    at HTMLButtonElement.nrWrapper ((index):9)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete in SearchBox does not work even in official example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049750/autocomplete-in-searchbox-does-not-work-even-in-official-example)

Answer (score 3):

My search button also started failing with the same error. I think a API change somewhere between V3.31 and V3.34 made the final argument to event.trigger required instead of optional.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#event.trigger

My code looked like this:

```
button.click(function () {

    google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'focus');
    google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
        keyCode: 13
    });
});
```

I added an empty third argument to the focus trigger, like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'focus', {});
```

and everything started working again. Hope this helps anyone in a similar situation!

Comment: Great catch. The minified `trigger` method ```ƒ (a,b,c){if(_.R.hasListeners(a,b)){var d=_.bb(arguments,2),e=vd(a,b),f;for(f in e){var g=e[f];g&&g.b.apply(g.f,d)}}}``` passes its `arguments` to some other `_.bb` that is probably doing a `.length` somewhere down the line on that 3rd arg. That 3rd arg can be anything that can have properties. Without the 3rd arg, this error is thrown: ```TypeError: Cannot set property 'handled' of undefined```