# Google Maps places search box stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

My app uses Google Map's Places library (via JS SDK) in order to autocomplete place search. It worked perfectly fine up until today... Now nothing shows up in autocomplete. I can see calls outgoing to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetQueryPredictions in Chrome Dev Tools, but not much returned there. If I enter some query in the search box (like Kraków) and hit enter, it will trigger places_changed event with one place, but formatted_address is "Poland "only, which is weird.

What's more, I've checked example in docs and it doesn't work either https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Anyone experience similar situation recently?

Comment: We've experienced the same issue in our app today.

Comment: Apparently google has bug on latest version 3.32. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49050513/190628 for fix.